# Hide feature flag when viewed/visited in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a new feature in my Rails project. I need to insert a "New!" flag in its menu, so user will notice that a new feature is available. Once the new feature page is visited, this "flag" must disappear.

How is it possible with Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 1):

The absolute simplest way is to look for a sawFeatureX cookie and set it when the page is rendered or the user dismisses the notification.

A more robust solution would be to store the info on the user model in the db, but that ends up giving you a lot of one-off boolean fields which may or may not be what you want.

There are MANY variations. You could use something like HelloBar to point out the new content without inlining it into the menu. So. Many. UX. Variations.

But for a one-time thing, a cookie or db-backed solution seems simple and easy.

Answer (score 0):

I hate this problem.

A cookie is easy, but gross and doesn't scale. You really don't want to pay the price of sending this data back and forth on every request until the end of time.

Saving on the user record seems like a sin against database design.

A separate DB table with all these "I saw feature X" seems like such overkill and I hate something that is just going to grow without bound being in my main DB.

You can put it in Redis, memcached, but do you really need to store it in RAM? that's the most expensive place to do this.

I think the ideal solution is something like https://www.prefab.cloud/documentation/once_and_only_once which is a service (i wrote) that stores this little "bob saw X" off in a database I don't need to manage/care. It handles cacheing etc so that it's as fast as having it in Redis/etc but durable and doesn't get expired.